# WPF MVVM using LINQ to SQL

Tags: wpf, mvvm, linq-to-sql, sql-update

I have binded my customer name textbox to Customer Model and set the mode to two way now I want to update the edited name to database. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague as it doesn't say whether you wanted this on PropertyChanged or when you have a button with either Click event handling or ICommand binding on it.

The decision when to update is totally down to the business model that you are applying.  Generally speaking, it's never a good idea to update directly from a PropertyChanged event because it might be a temporary edit and you may wish to update against.

For example, if you have UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, then as soon as a character is type, the Property is updated with the new value and if you implmented iNotifyPropertyChanged events, that would instantly fire an update to your database.  Because a database connection is transient, usually over a network, it may or may not be available, and it may or may not timeout during a partial update.  Thus, you could end up locking up your code or if multi-threading, causing race conditions.

Therefore, it's always better to implement the changes via a save button or when the screen is closed/navigated away from (such as what iOS/Android do).